# Data cleaning using regex sql or java

Tags: java, regex

I want to use regex sql to remove all the letters after decimal, like A26.5 H to A26.5, A26.5GH to A26.5,  how can I use regex ?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to use regex in sql, or use sql to pick data, then do replacing in Java which later will update it with new data?

Comment: I am trying both, but first, I tried using java.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in java for each target string:

```
^([A-Za-z]*\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[\sa-zA-Z]*$
```

and replace by

```
$1
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aSWvx0/1)

Comment: If that worked for you then you can try one thing: accepting it as answer which you haven't done yet for any of your questions ... this is how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @RAVIMISHRA can you accept this answer if this worked for you. So that other people find it helpful?